# PHP Preg_replace() function

Tags: php

How to use the preg_replace function to replace

/c83403.403/

Example:
https://startimage.ca/c83403.403/ahmedmynewpix.jpg

another example:
https://startimage.ca/c2.3403.403/ahmedmynewpix2.jpg

It always start with /c..../ I want to replace that with ""

I am trying the following but not working
$str = '/c..../';
$str = preg_replace('/+[0-9]', '', $str);

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$str = 'https://startimage.ca/c83403.403/ahmedmynewpix.jpg';
$str = preg_replace('|/c[0-9.]+|', '', $str);
echo $str; # https://startimage.ca/ahmedmynewpix.jpg'
```

... or

```
$str = preg_replace('|/c[0-9.]+|', '/c', $str);
echo $str; # https://startimage.ca/c/ahmedmynewpix.jpg'
```

The point is that you replace anything starting from `/c` and containing either digits or dot symbol (`.`) - with either empty space or `/c` string, depending on what you need. )